# Four riddles with the same answer

Tags: riddle

**The answer has to be able to answer all of the riddles below.**

1. Is an angel.. but doesn't live in heaven.
2. Has the power to fly.. but isn't a bird.
3. Is related to Mother Nature's sister.
4. Cares about people.. but loves to shoot them too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one’s more of a long shot…. Could it be

> Cupid?

1. Is an angel.. but doesn't live in heaven.

> Cupid is a demigod, and lives on Mount Olympus

2. Has the power to fly.. but isn't a bird.

> Cupid has wings and can fly

3. Is related to Mother Nature's sister.

> Cupid is the daughter of Zeus, who’s the grandson of Gaia… so technically related to the Greek Goddess of the Earth (and her sister). Also related to Demeter, Goddess of the Harvest? Potentially Mother Nature could refer to Persephone, of whom Aphrodite is a sister and Cupid’s mother.

4. Cares about people.. but loves to shoot them too!

> Cares about people falling in love, but shoots them with his arrows to make it happen.

Comment: "long shot" heheh

Comment: Lol, and that was unintentional too haha